# Getting an error from adding to a NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

```
main_dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *insert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[insert addObject:main_event];      
NSString *count = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",total_count];
[main_dict setValue:insert forKey:count];
```

I initialized the NSDictionary, main_dict and the NSMustableArray, insert. Then I added the main_event to the insert array. Finally added that array into dictionary with the key value.

I got SIG_ABRT signal when I stepped into the `[main_dict setValue:insert forKey:count];`

What's wrong? I have all the elements initialized and have values, but still SIG_ABRT.

Comment: A few things:  Use specific object constructors: `count = ...; insert = [NSArray arrayWithObject:main_event]; main_dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:insert forKey:count];`; Easier if you use the new syntax (XCode 4.5+): `count = ...; main_dict = @{count:@[main_event]}`. Even easier if you can use `count` as an `NSNumber` instead of a string: `main_dict = @{@(count):@[main_event]};`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the data type of `main_dict` to mutable type. `NSDictionary` is an immutable type and you can not edit it. So change it as `main_dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify NSDictionary type instance. Just replace

```
main_dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

to

```
main_dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

will solve this issue.

Comment: You also need to change main_dict's type from NSDictionary * to NSMutableDictionary * otherwise you'll get a compiler error trying to call setValue. Actually, there should already be such an error or warning. Never ignore compiler warnings. All code should compile clean.